# HTTPS site presents error temporarily unavailable and after 5 seconds it refreshes and works

Tags: php, linux, apache, webserver

I have a scenario that I have never seen in my life.

I have an apache webserver that was set up by a developer.

A Let's Encrypt certificate has been generated

And when accessing the site in HTTPS it displays the error below:

> This website cannot be accessed. The https://*myurl.com*/conecta/ page
> may be temporarily unavailable or may have been moved permanently to a
> new web address. ERR_FAILED

If it stays on the page, after about 3 ~ 5 seconds the page will refresh and display the site normally in https;

I have never seen anything like this and if anyone knows where the error is I will be very grateful, I am 2 days in it.

HTTPD.CONF FILE:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80 443

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

 emerg.

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>

    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types


    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>


AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>

    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-available/*.conf
```

SSL.CONF

```
#   o ExportCertData:
#     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
#     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
#     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
#     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
#     into CGI scripts.
#   o StdEnvVars:
#     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
#     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
#     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
#     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
#     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
#   o StrictRequire:
#     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
#     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
#     and no other module can change it.
#   o OptRenegotiate:
#     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
#     directives are used in per-directory context.
#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

#   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
#   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
#   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
#   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
#   approach you can use one of the following variables:
#   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
#     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
#     SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
#     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
#     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
#   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
#     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
#     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
#     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
#     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
#     works correctly.
#   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
#   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
#   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
#   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
#   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
#   "force-response-1.0" for this.
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#   Per-Server Logging:
#   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
#   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

/sites-available
MYDOMAIN.CONF

```
<VirtualHost app.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName app.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias app.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app.mydomain.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =app.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

MYDOMAIN-LE-SSL.CONF:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost app.mydomain.com:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName app.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias app.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app.mydomain.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomian.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomain.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I still have some other .conf files in the conf.d directory and if necessary I can post their contents:
autoindex.conf  php56-php.conf  php.conf.rpmsave  README   userdir.conf

Thanks!!!

Comment: What do your logs say?